# Choosing generalisation or association (aggregation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

My IOS application includes similar views that draws data from server and visualise them.
I want to combine common networking code in a class to ensure reusability and to avoid repeated code.

Should I locate networking code in a super class or in an associated class. I couldn't make a decision which method should I use, generalisation or association (aggregation)?

What would you do if you were me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good solution to create view superclass for storing client-server communication code due causes:

1. Client-server communication isn't a part of data presentation (View). Logically it is separate entity.
2. If you use associated object you could use it anywhere, not only in Views that represent loaded data. It makes your architecture more flexible.

There are more reasons to not use inheritance in your case but I think these two points are enough to make decision.
To my mind you should use associated object (aggregation).